# Undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass for @micropost.save in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I know the issue here is that I am trying to save a nil value but I have been debugging for hours and I can't figure out what seems to be causing the value to be nil. This occurs when I hit post on the micropost button below the text field.

**Microposts Controller**

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def create
      if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'show'
      end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private 
      def micropost_params
        params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
      end
end
```

**Micropost Model**

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

**View Show**

```
    <% provide(:title, @user.first_name) %>
      <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-4">
         <section class="user_info">
           <h1>
           <%= gravatar_for @user %>
           <%= @user.first_name %>
           </h1>
         </section>
        </aside>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <aside class="col-md-4">
        <section class="user_info">
          <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        </section>
        <section class="micropost_form">
          <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
        </section>
      </aside>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
        <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
          <ol class="microposts">
            <%= render @microposts %>
          </ol>
         <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
     <% end %>
     </div>
```

Comment: `@micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)` line is missing in `def create`. you can only `save` something, which is _instantiated_. In

Comment: Sorry, having trouble formatting the code in comments so I put my follow up question as an answer below.

Comment: not really. In the `else` section you are rendering 'show` view which is using `@user` variable. but `@user` is not technically defined in `create`.`else` section should have redefined `@user` and `@microposts`

Comment: why does user need to be defined in create again if it's rendering an action that already defines it? Also when I add @user = User.find(params[:id]) before render 'show', I get ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MicropostsController#create and Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Comment: You are not defining it again. `create` method is different, `show` method is different. In else you are using show view rather than method. use `@user = current_user`. You don't have `params[:id]` at that point. Actually, your code and approach needs to be cleaned up; I will recommend you go through Rails edge tutorial.

Comment: I see what you mean, I haven't defined micropost or users in the micropost helper so I'm calling classes in the controller that don't exist/haven't been defined. I was following this: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts and they don't actually define these resources outside of the controllers so I wasn't quite following why it wasn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

Your create action should be

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)
  if @micropost.save
    flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

By default instance variables are nil

Comment: Sorry, having trouble formatting the code in comments so I put my follow up question as an answer below.